# Problem getting last characters until find "\" character?

Tags: python, split

Hi i don't know how to do this, in this example i want to get all the last characters until i find the "" character, usually in this way works but it seems that typing "" inside the split function doesn't work and the program gives me an error. So how to get all the last characters until i find the "" starting from the end?

```
string = 'C:\user\computer\myfile.txt'
a = string.split('\')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your string with '\':

```
string = 'C:\\user\\computer\\myfile.txt'
a = string.split('\\')
print(a)

# Output
['C:', 'user', 'computer', 'myfile.txt']
```

Comment: Ok thanks now it works i accepted the answer, can you explain me why using only "\" gives me an error? Because the strings with paths in general in Python works even with one "\"

Comment: @Forty966996. Escape strings in Python are introduced by backslash. Sometimes, it doesn't matter like `\c` or `\m` but sometimes the sequence means something like `\u` (a unicode sequence)

Comment: The best thing you can do in Python to deal with paths is to use `/`: `'C/user/computer/myfile.txt'`. You can also use `pathlib` or `os.path` module.

Comment: Ok i tried and only '/' is better much simple, thanks